# SQL query to count rows under 3 different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, group-by

So I want to create a single query which will return me names of `projects` and number of `assigments` which are related to `project` in particular severity. For example: table `assigment` contains:

```
 id  |                name                 | project_id  | severity  | 
-----+-------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+
 148 | Create background                   |         1   |          1|  
 184 | Create frontend                     |         1   |          1|  
 151 | Create Budged                       |         1   |          2|  
 155 | Assign all tasks                    |         1   |          3|    
 179 | Drink Beer                          |         1   |          1|
```

Table `project` contains only `name` and `id` as follows:

```
 id  |                name                 
-----+-------------------------------------
 1   | Very Important Project
```

I would like to create a single query which will return something like this:

```
projectid   |  projectname          | CriticalAssig| MediumAssig | LowAssig
------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+----------
```

This works for me at the moment:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.name, 
       Count(a1.id)  AS one, 
       Count(a2.id)  AS two, 
       Count (a3.id) AS three 
FROM   project p 
       INNER JOIN assign a1 
               ON a1.project_id = p.id 
       INNER JOIN assign a2 
               ON a2.project_id = p.id 
       INNER JOIN assign a3 
               ON a3.project_id = p.id 
WHERE  a2.severity = '2' 
       AND a1.severity = '1' 
       AND a3.severity = '3' 
GROUP  BY p.id, 
          p.name;
```

But result of this query is ridiculous in columns `one`, `two`, `three` I get numbers like `90000` (the same number everywhere) while the simple query `select count(*) from assig where project_id=x` returns `300`.

Can anyone point me where my mistake is located?

Comment: Assign has multiple rows for the same project_id and severity.  Did you mean you use `count(disinct id)`?

Comment: Do you want to count where the severity ='1' in the one col and severity ='2' int the two col and so on?

Comment: @MatBailie Thats the main idea that project can have multiple assigments with same severity, that is why I want to create report which can show how many critical, medium and low assigments are created to particular project

Comment: @PeterRing yes it is exacly what I am trying to achive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without any joins:

```
count(case when severity = 1 then 1 else null end) as one
```

(The problem in your current query is that you're multiplying the number of rows before grouping. When developing aggregates, run the query without the aggregate function calls and group by/having clauses, to see what you're actually counting, summing, etc.)

Comment: It works exactly as I wanted it to ! Thank You very much. I will check this one as an answer - it was first one which appeared.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
       SUM(a.severity = 1) AS one, 
       SUM(a.severity = 2) AS two, 
       SUM(a.severity = 3) AS three
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN assign a ON a.project_id = p.id  
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

**OR**

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.severity = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS one, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.severity = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS two, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.severity = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS three
FROM project p 
INNER JOIN assign a ON a.project_id = p.id  
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select p.id, 
p.name, 
count(case when severity = 1 then 1 else null end) as one, 
count(case when severity = 2 then 1 else null end) as two, 
count (case when severity = 3 then 1 else null end) as three
    from project p 
    inner join assign on assign.project_id = p.id 
    group by p.id, p.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use subquerys.

```
select p.id, p.name, 
count(SELECT * FROM project a where severity = 1 and p.id=a.id) as one, 
count(SELECT * FROM project a where severity = 2 and p.id=a.id) as two, 
count(SELECT * FROM project a where severity = 3 and p.id=a.id) as three
from project p
group by p.id, p.name;
```